# Preventing use of `cd ..` in bash?

Tags: bash, alias

I have set up an alias in my .bashrc as follows:

`alias u='cd ..'`

All is well in my world... until I type `cd ..` and cringe that I did not use my incredible new alias. In fact, with this particular thing, it's very ingrained. Hard to change my behavior - I need serious intervention.

So, I naturally tried to set up another alias to keep me from using `cd ..`:

`alias 'cd ..'='echo "Use your alias!"'`

But that apparently doesn't work. My thought is that this also might somehow conflict with the `u` alias, in some sort of infinite loop of aliasing.

Any ideas?

Comment: OK, to note: I don't care if this uses aliases or not - My real goal is to *stop* myself from using `cd ..` somehow. Perhaps I should change the question title?

Comment: I used to use `cd..` (no spaces) all the time in DOS.  Took me a while to break that habit in Linux back in the day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Anything more complicated that supplying a few extra arguments to a command is too much for an alias and requires a function instead. Use `builtin cd` to call the original.

```
cd () {
  if [ "$*" = ".." ]; then
    echo 1>&2 'Use your alias instead!'
    return 2
  else
    builtin cd "$@"
  fi
}
```

If you're running bash ≥4.0, I question the utility of this particular alias. Put `shopt -s autocd` in your `~/.bashrc`, and just type `..` or any other directory name to switch to it.

Comment: I might have to use this to break my `cd` habit... although... at work I wouldn't have access to `zsh` autocd... oh choices...